# How Do You Set Write Permissions But Not Read Or Modify - cPanel?

Tags: permissions, cpanel, chmod

I am building a site where the user needs to be able to upload files.

I want them to be able to upload files but not read them.

For example, if they upload "test.zip" i dont want them or another user to be able to go to "www.url.com/test.zip" and down load the file or read it if its a .txt etc.

I am using cPanel if that helps.

I have had a Google but all that appears is different combinations of permissions people requesting.

Answer (score 0):

To set a file to to allow the user and group to write to a file we will want to give the directory bothe the write and execute permissions.  Because unix permissions by adding the numbers of the permissions you want to grant we will add 1 (for execute) and 2 (for write ) to get 3.

1. = Execute (on directories this is the permission to open the directory)
2. = Write
3. = Sum of 1+2, so both Write and Execute
4. = Read
5. = Sum of 1+4, so Read and Execute
6. = Sum of 2+4, so Read/Write.
7. = Sum of 1+2+4, so Read, Write and Execute.

For a directory that will function as a write only folder we would want the permission of 3 (remembering the need of the executable to access the folder.

Now after calculating this number we need to set it three times.  Once for the user owning the file, once for the group, and once for others.  These are set by putting the three numbers in order.

So to set a folder for that only allows Write access for the user and group we would use 330.  In the chmod command used to set permissions it would look like:

```
chmod 330 ~/public_html/path/to/folder
```

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_permissions#Traditional_Unix_permissions
- http://www.dartmouth.edu/~rc/help/faq/permissions.html